# how to hash password in service layer?

Tags: laravel, hash

I'm trying to create an admin.
I use the repository and the service layer,
I want the password hash to be done in the service layer and repositories do admin storage only
how to don it???
this is my service layer `AdminService.php`

```
public function createAdmin(array $data):RedirectResponse
    {
        $this->admin_repository->createAdmin(data: $data);
        return redirect('admins');
    }
```

This is my repository `AdminRepository.php`

```
public function createAdmin(array $data):Admin|false
    {
        $admin = new Admin();
        $admin->name = $data['name'];
        $admin->email =$data['email'];
        $admin->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
        try {
            $admin->save();
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            Log::error(trans('repository.admin.create_error') . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return $admin;
    }
```

pleas help me!!!!!!!

Comment: What is the error or what does not work as expected?

Comment: This code works fine, but password hashing is logical, so it should not be done in a repository.
Must be hashed in the service layer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the password hashed in the "service layer", then do it there

```
public function createAdmin(array $data):RedirectResponse
{
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $this->admin_repository->createAdmin(data: $data);
    return redirect('admins');
}

public function createAdmin(array $data):Admin|false
{
    $admin = new Admin();
    $admin->name = $data['name'];
    $admin->email =$data['email'];
    $admin->password = $data['password'];
    try {
        $admin->save();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        Log::error(trans('repository.admin.create_error') . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return $admin;
}
```